# How to receive in php a post sent with RestSharp

Tags: php, json, restsharp

I need to receive in PHP an http post from RestSharp / 105.2.3.0, supposedly send me the following:

```
POST / api / Msg HTTP / 1.1
Accept: application / json
Authorization: Basic K9ykc3QyOmlmZWlnb2hjaGFpZ2hpZWxpaH53
User-Agent: RestSharp / 105.2.3.0
Content-Type: application / json
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Content-Length: 80
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"Name": "Bear", "LastName": "Lukas", "time": 797, "option": 1}
```

I tried to use the following code in php but it did not work, any ideas?

```
<?php 
$json_params=file_get_contents("php://input");
$decoded_params = json_decode($json_params,true);
foreach ($decoded_params as $dp){
echo $dp;
}
```

Comment: I'm facing same issue.
if you resolved issue, can you please share me idea. 

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, 
First the http request must be directed correctly to your URL that will receive the HEADS, second the command json_decode () only works with PHP 5.2 or higher, if you have an old version of PHP then download JSON.php from the web